# Не работает автозагрузка

Tags: php, автозагрузка

Есть проект

```
Project1
 app
    Commander.php
    Parser.php
    ShowReport.php
 result
 vendor
    composer
    autoload.php
.gitignore
composer.json
```

Классы Сommander,Parser, ShowReport находятся в namespace Project1. В классе Commander следующее подключение require ('../vendor/autoload.php'); При сomposer dumpautoload выдает "Generated autoload files containing 0 classes" Файл composer.json следующий

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Project1\\": "app/"
    }
  }
```

При запуске  выдает ошибку `PHP Warning:  require(../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yura/PhpstormProjects/Project1/app/Commander.php on line 11` Какие будут идеи?

Comment: Файл не найден. Путь некорректен. Возможно поможет указание полного пути к файлу.

Comment: Получился замкнутый круг: вы пытаетесь загрузить файл автозагрузки Компосера из файла класса, который будет доступен только после того, как автозагрузчик Компосера будет выполнен. Если у вас web-приложение - разместите загрузку файла автозагрузчика vendor/autoload.php в главном индексном файле, например index.php.

Comment: У меня из этого класса будут вызываться остальные. Соmmander -точка входа